# How do I call a WCF web service in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core

I followed this documentation on setting up a connected wcf service in VS and things worked nicely.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

However, now I'm struggling to figure out how to send this SOAP service my credentials (un, pwd).

Here's what the Connected Service looks like...

https://photos.app.goo.gl/hA6ABN2DNVtXW5KC8

How can I invoke and send my credentials?  Then view the result?

Comment: What have you tried and how did it fail? How were you calling the credentials to the SOAP service before?

Comment: would [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55141046/net-core-2-0-call-to-wcf-client-configuration) point you to an answer?

Comment: As it generates the client side code for you, simply pass user credentials via the code. Samples can be found like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-specify-client-credential-values Depending on your service side authentication mode, the user credentials might differ.

Answer (score 2):

You can call server-side methods and properties through the generated proxy class.Here is my demo:

[image]

This is a proxy class generated by WCF web service reference provider tool.We need to call services through these classes.

```
     class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client service1Client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ServiceReference1.Result> user=service1Client.GetUserDataAsync("Test");
        Result rr=user.Result;
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rr));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I create a client through the proxy class and call the service through the created client.

In your code,you also need to create a client like this, and then invoke or send your credentials through the client's method.

Comment: How configure URL for web service ? PRO environment, TEST environment...

Comment: How send credentials to Service1Client ? I get *The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'*